# SQL Server 2000 - Find dates when exactly records changed for user

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to find the dates when exactly the status really changed.

Order should be analysed from Start to end period:

here start period : 11-10-2014 End Period : 21-10-2014

Data:

```
ID, Name, Effective_date, Status

1 A 21-10-2014 OFF

2 A 20-10-2014 OFF

3 A 19-10-2014 On

4 A 18-10-2014 On

5 A 17-10-2014 On

6 A 16-10-2014 OFF

7 A 15-10-2014 On

8 A 14-10-2014 On

9 A 13-10-2014 OFF

10 A 12-10-2014 OFF

11 A 11-10-2014 OFF
```

SQL version : I am using SQL 2000.

Expected output:

```
ID, Name, Effective_date, Status

2 A 20-10-2014 OFF

5 A 17-10-2014 On

6 A 16-10-2014 OFF

8 A 14-10-2014 On

11 A 11-10-2014 OFF
```

Comment: Why you want to show record #2 if has the same status as #1? the status did change con #3...

Comment: I mentioned that Order should be analysed from Start to end period:

Here start period : 11-10-2014 
End Period : 21-10-2014

Also, I need to find when status exactly changed.

Comment: You can do this with a self join where current row status <> next row status.

Comment: Do you alawys have one record for each day?

Comment: HLGEM - No, not necessary. 
Sean - I tried but not success, can you please share some query for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following does the trick (Revised for 2000 compatibility).

```
DECLARE @Start_Period DATETIME
DECLARE @End_Period DATETIME
SET @Start_Period = '20141011'
SET @End_Period = '20141021'

SELECT
  B.ID,
  B.Name,
  B.Effective_date,
  B.Status
FROM
  ATable A
  LEFT JOIN
  ATable B ON 
    A.Name = B.Name
    AND
    B.ID = (
             SELECT TOP 1
               ID
             FROM
               ATable 
             WHERE
               ID < A.ID AND 
               Name = A.Name
             ORDER BY
               ID DESC
           )  
WHERE
  A.Status <> B.Status
  AND 
  A.Effective_date between @Start_Period AND @End_Period                      

UNION ALL

-- Add the last row for the period
SELECT 
  A.* 
FROM
  ATable A
JOIN
(
  SELECT
    MAX(A.ID) AS ID,
    A.Name
  FROM
    ATable A
  WHERE
     A.Effective_date between @Start_Period AND @End_Period  
  GROUP BY
    A.Name
) T ON A.Name = T.Name AND A.ID = T.ID 
ORDER BY
  B.Name,
  B.ID
```